# Is it possible to configure /etc/hosts on a per network basis?

Tags: hosts

I have a server at home with a domain name (let's call it domain.name). On my laptop, I have added this line to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.7 domain.name
```

At home, this is great, but at others places this is not relevant at all. How can I setup /etc/hosts to use this line only when at home?
Configuring my home router is not an option, but using another FOSS software would be a valid solution.